Mixpanel reaching limits
Straight forward question about Mixpanel free tier !
What would happen if on the free tier and the limit of tracked events is reached
will it fail silently ?
or will the user see any error message ?
Regards

When the free tier limit is reached you will be notified in-product and will have a limited product experience until the next billing period.
